# Configurar git log --oneline

Tags: git, log, archlinux, zsh

Buen día con todos, esta es mi primera pregunta en esta gran comunidad, estoy aprendiendo y espero pronto aportar con lo aprendido.

Al utilizar el comando git log --oneline, se abre un editor en el cual puedo visualizar la información de los commits realizados, del cual luego debo salir presionando :q; sin embargo, he visto en algunos videotutoriales, que, al usar el mismo comando, les muestra directamente la información de los commits en la misma línea de comandos, sin necesidad de un editor, ¿cómo puedo lograr lo mismo?. Estuve buscando información, pero no logro dar con la respuesta.

(Estoy utilizando zsh en una distribución Arch Linux)

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comportamiento que describes parece indicar que tu comando `git log --oneline` está utilizando un paginador (como `less` o `more`) para mostrar los resultados. Para evitar que se abra el paginador y mostrar los resultados directamente en la línea de comandos, puedes configurar la variable de entorno `GIT_PAGER` o la opción de configuración de Git `core.pager` para que no utilice ningún paginador.

Para desactivar el paginador temporalmente para un solo comando, ejecuta:

```bash
GIT_PAGER=cat git log --oneline
```

Si deseas desactivar el paginador para todos los comandos de Git en tu sesión actual, ejecuta:

```bash
export GIT_PAGER=cat
```

Para desactivar el paginador de forma permanente para todos los comandos de Git en tu sistema, ejecuta:

```bash
git config --global core.pager cat
```

Esto debería permitirte ver los resultados de `git log --oneline` directamente en la línea de comandos sin necesidad de un editor. Decime si te funciona, quedo a tu disposición para lo que quieras y/o necesites. Saludos!

Comment: Adicionalmente, en mi experiencia, si la salida del comando va a ser de menos de una página (según el tamaño del terminal que tengas en ese momento), git evita arrancar el _pager_.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Inkinvissible, me ha funcionado correctamente lo indicado en tu respuesta. Saludos!